# Div keeps going on top of other div, even though it has a lower z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

My page is [here](http://www.parkroo.com/k2/choose/spelling/), my stylesheet is [here](http://www.parkroo.com/k2/style.css), and the text saying 'hello' many times is going over the navigation menu, even though it has a lower z-index.

What is happening?

Comment: what you want ....... it's fine

Comment: when you scroll down, the hello text goes over the navigation menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main content div isn't going over the navigation, it just looks like it because you have no background colour on the navigation, so it's see-through.

If you give your navigation menu a background colour you should see that it hides the text as your scroll down.

I have only tested this in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Set a background colour for the `#nav` e.g. `#212121`

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you just define

```
ul#navmenu{
z-index:2;
}
```